# Dropping a line from a categorical point in a pgfplot scatter plot

Tags: pgfplots

This is a scatter plot, where x-axis is categorical and y-axis is numerical. I want to draw a perpendicular line from the point `(X, 9)` to `(X, 0)`. I have tried `\draw[doshed] (X, 0) -- (X, 9);` but it didn't work.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{pgfplotstable}


\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{semilogyaxis}[
            symbolic x coords={X},
            xtick=data,
            xticklabel style = {font=\footnotesize},
            enlargelimits=0.2,
            nodes near coords,
            every node near coord/.append style={xshift=0.5cm, yshift=0.1cm},
            y tick label style={/pgf/number format/.cd,%
            set thousands separator={,}, fixed},
          ]

      \addplot[color=blue,mark=*, only marks,
        point meta=explicit symbolic] coordinates {
        (X,     9) [9\%]
    };

        % THE LINE I WANT TO DRAW
        % \draw[doshed] (X, 0) -- (X, 9); 

    \end{semilogyaxis}%
\end{tikzpicture}%



\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `ycomb` handler to achieve what you want. For details, please have a look at the comments in the code. (Please also note that I have removed all the unnecessary parts of your code.)

```
% used PGFPlots v1.16
\documentclass[border=5pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{semilogyaxis}[
        symbolic x coords={X,Y},
        xtick=data,
        nodes near coords,
    ]

        \addplot [
            mark=*,
            only marks,
            point meta=explicit symbolic,
            % -------------------------------------------------------------
            % use `ycomb' to draw a vertical line at each data point
            ycomb,
            % state the color and line style of the vertical line
            draw=black,
            dashed,
            % because the above commands also influence the `mark' style,
            % we need to reset it to what we want
            every mark/.append style={
                solid,
                blue,
            },
            % -------------------------------------------------------------
        ] coordinates {
            (X, 9)  [9\%]
            (Y, 10) [bla]
        };

    \end{semilogyaxis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: image showing the result of above code]

Comment: This is more elegant. However the Ulrike Fischer's solution does work.

Answer (score 3):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{pgfplotstable}


\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{semilogyaxis}[
            symbolic x coords={X},
            xtick=data,
            xticklabel style = {font=\footnotesize},
            enlargelimits=0.2,
            nodes near coords,
            every node near coord/.append style={xshift=0.5cm, yshift=0.1cm},
            y tick label style={/pgf/number format/.cd,%
            set thousands separator={,}, fixed},
          ]

      \addplot[color=blue,mark=*, only marks,
        point meta=explicit symbolic] coordinates {
        (X,     9) [9\%]
    };
        \node[circle,fill,inner sep=1.6pt, red] at (axis cs:X,12) {};

        % THE LINE I WANT TO DRAW
         \draw[dashed] (axis cs:X, 0) -- (axis cs:X, 9);

    \end{semilogyaxis}%
\end{tikzpicture}%



\end{document}
```

[image]